# How send object as a property from form

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Spring, Hibernate.
I have an QuestionEntity, which contains another entity (TestEntity):

```
public class QuestionEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "question_text")
private String questionText;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "test_id")
private TestEntity testEntity; ...}
```

From html page i want to add TestEntity as Object (Logic is: the test has the question)

```
<form name="question" action="/exam/addQuestion/" method="post">
Текст вопроса:<br>
<input type="text" name="questionText.text">
<input type="hidden" name="testEntity" value="${testEntity}">
<input type="submit" name="addTest" value="add">
```

Reciving:

```
    @PostMapping("addQuestion")
public String addQuestion(@ModelAttribute ("question") QuestionEntity questionEntity){
    testService.saveOrUpdate(questionEntity);
    return "redirect:/exam/getall";
}
```

but spring gets ${testEntity} as String so i have the error:

> Field error in object 'question' on field 'testEntity': rejected value
>   [TestEntity{id=3, name='Узнай свой психотип'}]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.question.testEntity,typeMismatch.testEntity,typeMismatch.exampro.entity.TestEntity,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [question.testEntity,testEntity]; arguments []; default message
>   [testEntity]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of
>   type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'exampro.entity.TestEntity'
>   for property 'testEntity'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'exampro.entity.TestEntity' for
>   property 'testEntity': no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found]

How is it correct to send? Great thanks for any help.

Comment: did you google on how to access java properties from form with hibernate?

Comment: yes,i use @PostMapping("addQuestion")
    public String addQuestion(@ModelAttribute ("question") QuestionEntity questionEntity){        
        questionService.saveOrUpdate(question
    } i will add it to the post